# I am able to read the contents of CSV file through NSScanner, how to move it to the array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv

I am able to read the contents of CSV file through NSScanner, but how can I move it to an array?

The following is the code which I am using, I have hard-coded it to read to move the data into the array. But it isn't working...

```
NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example PV" ofType: @"csv"];
NSError *error;

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
} 
scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];    
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n, "]];

NSString *Time = nil, *LVV = nil, *LVP = nil; 
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&Time] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&LVV] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&LVP] )
{
    arrayItems = [LVV componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


    NSLog(@"%@",arrayItems);

}
```

Comment: It seems as though you are overwriting your array in that while loop. Set up the string first, and then use `componentsSeparatedByString`, and your array will be structured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MSgambel... I am new the coding in Iphone. Can u just help me with explaining in much depth. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could benefit from Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser that you can find here: http://davedelong.com/portfolio ?

It will parse your file or string and put it all into an array of arrays.